# Correlation functions in the interaction picture

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian, path-integral, vacuum, correlation-functions

When deriving Feynman path integral for QFTs, my professor assumed that the Hamiltonian was given by:
$$H = \int d^{3}x \bigg{(}\frac{1}{2}\hat{\pi}^{2}+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla \hat{\phi})^{2}+\frac{1}{2}m^{2}\hat{\phi}^{2}\bigg{)}+\cdots = \int d^{3}x \bigg{(}\frac{1}{2}\hat{\pi}^{2}+V[\hat{\phi}]\bigg{)} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $V= V[\hat{\phi}]$ is the part of the Hamiltonian density that does not depend on the conjugate momenum operator $\hat{\pi}$. He then derived:
$$\langle 0| 0 \rangle =  N \int D\phi(x) e^{iS[\phi]} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
where $N$ is a normalizing constant. After that, he defined correlation functions:
$$G^{(n)}(x_{1},...,x_{n}) = \langle 0| T\phi(x_{1})\cdots \phi(x_{n})|0\rangle = N\int D\phi(x) \phi(x_{1})\cdots \phi(x_{n})e^{iS[\phi(x),\partial_{\mu}\phi(x)]} \tag{3}\label{3}$$
and, putting $\langle 0| 0 \rangle = 1$, it becomes:
$$G^{n}(x_{1},...,x_{n}) = \frac{\int D\phi(x) \phi(x_{1})\cdots \phi(x_{n})e^{iS[\phi(x),\partial_{\mu}\phi(x)]}}{\int D\phi(x) e^{iS[\phi(x),\partial_{\mu}\phi(x)]}} \tag{4}\label{4}$$

After that, we suddenly began to consider generating functionals of the form:
$$Z[J] = N \int D\phi(x) e^{i\int d^{4}x(\mathcal{L}_{0}+\mathcal{L}_{\text{int}}+J(x)\phi(x))} \tag{5}\label{5}$$
for the interaction picture of an arbitrary system.

So, I have some questions:

**Question 1:** As far as I understand, the Hamiltonian (\ref{1}) allows us to consider scalar fields with interactions, since the term $V[\hat{\phi}]$ is being considered. How is the vaccum is defined, in this more general case? It is defined as the state $H|0\rangle = 0$ or the state associated with the smallest eigenvalue of $H$?

**Question 2:** From expression (\ref{5}), I deduce that the path integral and related relations (e.g. eqs. (\ref{2}) to (\ref{4})) are valid and remain unchanged for arbitrary Hamiltonians, even with interacting terms (or, at least, to more general Hamiltonians). Is this correct?

**Question 3:** What would be the interpretation of the correlations functions $G^{(n)}(x_{1},...,x_{n})$ *in the interacting picture*? I didn't find any discussion on my professor notes or Peskin & Schroeder's book.